# How to convert some R functions to Python?

Tags: python, r

I need to convert R code to Python, but I'm facing some problems with this funcions:

```
table_NameUrl= read.csv(file= "DadosPanu.txt", header= F, sep= "\n")
 
table_Size= length(table_NameUrl[[1]])
 
sequence= seq(1, size, by= 2)
```

The output of `table_Size` in R:

> 34

So I converted to Python like that:

```
table_Size = len(table_NameUrl)
```

And it's works.

In R, the output of `sequence` function is:

> 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33

But when I tried to convert to Python, I changed `seq()` to `np.linspace()` and the output is:

> array([ 1.        ,  1.67346939,  2.34693878,  3.02040816,
> 3.69387755,
> 4.36734694,  5.04081633,  5.71428571,  6.3877551 ,  7.06122449,
> 7.73469388,  8.40816327,  9.08163265,  9.75510204, 10.42857143,
> 11.10204082, 11.7755102 , 12.44897959, 13.12244898, 13.79591837,
> 14.46938776, 15.14285714, 15.81632653, 16.48979592, 17.16326531,
> 17.83673469, 18.51020408, 19.18367347, 19.85714286, 20.53061224,
> 21.20408163, 21.87755102, 22.55102041, 23.2244898 , 23.89795918,
> 24.57142857, 25.24489796, 25.91836735, 26.59183673, 27.26530612,
> 27.93877551, 28.6122449 , 29.28571429, 29.95918367, 30.63265306,
> 31.30612245, 31.97959184, 32.65306122, 33.32653061, 34.        ])

But I need the same output of R function.

Another problem that I face is:

```
for i in sequence:
 print(paste("Table name: ", as.character(table_NameUrl[[1]][i]), sep=""))
 print(paste("URL: ", as.character(table_NameUrl[[1]][i+1]), sep=""))
 tableName= table_NameUrl[[1]][i]
 tableUrl= table_NameUrl[[1]][i+1]
```

How to convert `[[1]][i]` and `[[1]][i+1]` to Python?

In R, the output of `tableName` and `tableUrl` are:

> 'Panu 2.1.1, 2.1.5'

and

> '/t/2093/p/2000,2010/v/93/c86/2776,2777,2778,2779,2780,2781/c2/0,4,5/c1/1,2/'

**Thanks in advance if anyone can help me!**

P.S.: My actual python code:

```
table_NameUrl = pd.read_csv("DadosPanu.txt", sep=";", header= None)
table_Size = len(table_NameUrl)
sequence = np.arange(1, table_Size, 2)
for i in sequence:
    tableName = table_NameUrl[[1]][i]
    tableUrl = table_NameUrl[[1]][i + 1]
    fileName = (tableName + ".csv")
    ro.globalenv['fileName'] = fileName
    last_url = "/n3/all/n6/in%20n3%2028"
    url = (tableUrl + last_url)
    ro.globalenv['url'] = url
    ro.r('table= get_sidra(api= url)')
    ro.r('write.csv(table, file= fileName, row.names = F)')
```

P.S.²: Question answer: How to convert `[[1]][i]` and `[[1]][i+1]` to Python?
[How to get CSV odd and even lines in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406792/how-to-get-csv-odd-and-even-lines-in-python/69407082#69407082)

Comment: `np.arange(1, size, 2)` instead of `np.linspace`. Please provide your actual python code, not just hints of what function you used.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSzczesny, I will add my python code now.