# How to get CSV odd and even lines in Python?

Tags: python, r

I'm converting R script to Python.

My actual Python code:

```
table_NameUrl = pd.read_csv("Data.txt", sep=";", header= None)
table_Size = len(table_NameUrl)
sequence = np.arange(1, table_Size, 2)
for i in sequence:
    print("Table name: " + str(table_NameUrl[[1]][i]))
    print("URL: " + str(table_NameUrl[[1]][i + 1]))
    tableName = table_NameUrl[[1]][i]
    tableUrl = table_NameUrl[[1]][i + 1]
    fileName = (tableName + ".csv")
    ro.globalenv['fileName'] = fileName
    last_url = "/n3/all/n6/in%20n3%2028"
    url = (tableUrl + last_url)
    ro.globalenv['url'] = url
    ro.r('table= get_sidra(api= url)')
    ro.r('write.csv(table, file= fileName, row.names = F)')
```

In R, I can get CSV odd and even lines with: `table_NameUrl[[1]][i]` and `table_NameUrl[[1]][i + 1]`

But in Python `[[1]][i]` and `[[1]][i + 1]` it didn't work.

The error is:

```
"None of [Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Short version of CSV:

> Panu 2.1.1, 2.1.5

> /t/2093/p/2000,2010/v/93/c86/2776,2777,2778,2779,2780,2781/c2/0,4,5/c1/1,2/

> Panu 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.1.9, 5.1.10

> /t/1612/p/2013,2014,2015,2016,2017/v/109,216,214/c81/2688,2691,2692,2694,2696,2708,2702,2715,2703/

> Panu 5.1.8

> /t/839/p/2013,2014,2015,2016,2017/v/109,216,214/c81/114254/

In R, the output of `tableName = table_NameUrl[[1]][i]` is the name of table, e.g.:

`Panu 2.1.1, 2.1.5`

And the output of `tableUrl = table_NameUrl[[1]][i + 1]` is the url, e.g.:
`/t/2093/p/2000,2010/v/93/c86/2776,2777,2778,2779,2780,2781/c2/0,4,5/c1/1,2/`

Can someone help me to convert this function?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), you can use the `iloc` function to select rows in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

table_NameUrl = pd.read_csv("Data.txt", sep=";", header= None)
even_rows = table_NameUrl.iloc[::2]
odd_rows = table_NameUrl.iloc[1::2]
```

OR

```
even_rows = table_NameUrl.iloc[lambda x: x.index % 2 == 0]
odd_rows = table_NameUrl.iloc[lambda x: x.index % 2 == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two functions to get the even or odd rows of a dataframe:

```py
def get_even_rows(dataframe):
    return dataframe[[i % 2 == 0 for i in range(df.shape[0])]]


def get_odd_rows(dataframe):
    return dataframe[[i % 2 != 0 for i in range(df.shape[0])]]
```